# Static class method in go language

Tags: oop, go

I am looking at the example code at:  https://golang.org/pkg/net/rpc/

```
type Arith int

func (t *Arith) Multiply(args *Args, reply *int) error {
    *reply = args.A * args.B
    return nil
}
```

From an OOP perspective, `Multiply` seems like a static method which doesn't access any data in `Arith` class; as the variable `t` is not used. Does it mean that `int` in `type Arith int` does not have any significance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't have anything to do with OOP, it's simply that the rpc package's convention works by exporting methods from an "object" (with object here meaning any value with a non-empty method set)

The `int` is significant as the type of `Arith`, but it's not significant in this particular example, since the receiver is never referenced in the methods.

So yes, this example is kind of like a static class, but try not to map Java OOP ideas to Go, because Go is very different, as there are no "classes" or inheritance.

Comment: In fact, I'm kind of curious why the example doesn't use `struct{}` which is the usual suspect for "who cares what this even is?"

Comment: @Jsor: probably because that particular example (and most of "net/rpc") are very old, predating go1 be a few years (circa 2009). Plus the extra 4-8 bytes allocated to register its methods aren't going to make any difference in the program overall.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to call simulating an static method, despite the fact it isn't, is as follows:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Arith struct {
}

func (Arith) Multiply(a float32, b float32) float32 {
    return a * b
}

func main() {
    result := (Arith).Multiply(Arith{}, 15, 25)
    fmt.Println(result)
}
```

But from my point of view, it is less understandable than placing this method in a separate package `arith` outside from class `Arith`

Comment: What does `(Arith)` in `main` mean?

Comment: Oh it refers to the struct definition itself. I got it.